# Routing on Flask-appbuilder - build Error

Tags: python, http, flask, jinja2, flask-appbuilder

Trying to load my homepage and getting build error, that it cant build the url for the endpoint 'Myview.general', this was working fine for 2 months before today,

## view.py

```
class Myview(BaseView):
    route_base = "/home"

    @has_access
    @expose('/general', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    @appbuilder.app.route('/general', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def general(self):

        if request.method == 'POST':
            bucket = request.form['bucket']
            session['bucket'] = bucket
            return redirect(url_for('HomeView.files'))
        else:
            buckets = get_buckets_list()
            return render_template(
                'index.html',
                base_template=appbuilder.base_template,
                appbuilder=appbuilder,
                buckets=buckets
            )
```

## HTML Snippet

```
        <form class="select-bucket" action="{{ url_for('HomeView.general')}}" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="bucket" value="{{ bucket['Name'] }}"/>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">
                <i class="fa fa-folder-open"></i>
            </button>
        </form>
```